# Does android sliding window support EditText field?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-edittext, sliding-window

I have a sliding window view in my android application which contains 3 xml layouts. In one of the xml files i have an `EditText` field and a button below it. My problem is that i am not able to enter the values in `EditText` field even though i have specified my `OnEditorActionListener` in the code. Is there any solution to this?

Comment: Firstly, what do you mean by sliding window view? It would be more helpful if you specified what kind of view container your are using instead of "sliding-window-view". I can think of many ways of implementing a sliding-window-view. So please specify what you are using.
Secondly, you do not need to specify an `onEditorActionListener` to enter text in an `EditText`.
You need to explain your problem in more detail, provide code snippets, that would help people answer your question.

Comment: sliding window view is a  view that comprises of 1 or more xml layouts and the user is free to slide from one screen to another.

Comment: do paste your xml and codes.